# Extends UnderlineInputBorder class in Google Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to modify the behavior of the UnderlineInputBorder in Flutter by extending it. **But the Flutter always called the draw() method of the superclass (UnderlineInputBorder) instead of my _PremiseInputBorder** as bellow.

Code for the TextField widget:

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
          border: _PremiseInputBorder()),
      )
```

Code for my custom border class:

```
class _PremiseInputBorder extends UnderlineInputBorder {
  const _PremiseInputBorder() : super();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {
    double gapStart,
    double gapExtent = 0.0,
    double gapPercentage = 0.0,
    TextDirection textDirection,}) {

    if (borderRadius.bottomLeft != Radius.zero ||     
      borderRadius.bottomRight != Radius.zero)
      canvas.clipPath(getOuterPath(rect, textDirection: textDirection));
      Offset leftRect = Offset(rect.left, rect.bottom - 5.0);
      Offset rightRect = Offset(rect.right, rect.bottom - 5.0);
      canvas.drawLine(leftRect, rightRect, borderSide.toPaint());
    }
  }
```

Comment: What `draw` method are you talking about? Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: Is yours never called or is it called and UnderlineInputBorder as well?

Comment: Yes, I tried `flutter clean` but the problem still remains. As my code snippet above, since I declared `border: _PremiseInputBorder()` in `TextField`, it should call my `_PremiseInputBorder` instead of `UnderlineInputBorder`. There is no other place it call `UnderlineInputBorder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UnderlineInputBorder` has

```
@override
  UnderlineInputBorder copyWith({ BorderSide borderSide, BorderRadius borderRadius }) {
    return UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: borderSide ?? this.borderSide,
      borderRadius: borderRadius ?? this.borderRadius,
    );
  }
```

which returns an `UnderlineInputBorder` even when you extend the class.

If you add to `_PremiseInputBorder`

```
  @override
  UnderlineInputBorder copyWith(
      {BorderSide borderSide, BorderRadius borderRadius}) {
    return _PremiseInputBorder();
  }
```

it will call your `paint()` method.

There are other methods that do similar things like `scale()`, `lerpFrom()`, `lerpTo()` but they were not called in your simple example.
You need to override these as well to make it all scenarios.

Comment: Glad to hear! .